# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck up on boot screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04

I'm using ASUS model A53E notebook with 4GB RAM and 500GB HDD. I allocated 100GB for Ubuntu, and Ubuntu has more than 20GB free space. It also has Windows 7 and it's working perfectly. Usually I miss the battery warning and my laptop often gets shut down, but yesterday when I rebooted the Ubuntu system it's hanging on:

```
Started Gnome Display Manager.
Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
```

After these two lines nothing is happening.

I tried Boot-Repair and `grub-update` and Boot-Repair Advanced options, but still got no results. Ubuntu still stops at the above lines.

What precautions should I take in future so this won't happen? What will happen if I'm in a serious development phase working for some clients? Is Ubuntu stable?

Comment: I would boot a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media) and `fsck` (file system check) your partition(s).  If I lose power, it's usually my first step before I try booting.

Comment: used fsck too, then ran boot-repair....still stucking up at `Started Hold until boot process finishes up.` and the boot never finishes...

Comment: Have you switched to runlevel 1 (ie. add a '1' to your linux [kernel] line so it stops at runlevel 1 & looked for clues in logs. Also removing 'quiet splash' may reveal more. You could also just login to terminal (ctrl+alt+f4 for example) and look for clues there too in logs.  I might look for what was last done before power off, or do a search (I'd run this from a 'live' system) for latest file(s) in hopes of clue as to what system was last doing when power went off for clues as to what it was doing.. You may recall what it was doing so can narrow down where to look (what I'd do)

Comment: No, not tried that but like to. Will Level 1 go into rescue mode? 

But yes, will try to get the log file. Was browsing when power went off. Have a live USB still no clue, how to get back the old system.

Comment: Tried so many things... it seems the themes and display driver are troubling...Please let me know how to switch to runlevel 1?

Comment: At grub you can add a " 1 " to the linux kernel line to stop the boot at runlevel 1 (default is 5), where at grub you press <E> to edit the entry instead of <ENTER> to load.  Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Comment: Already used GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset" with no change, will try to add 1 at run. As we're not getting prompt to try "systemctl set-default runlevel1.target". Believe we need a tool to analyze and fix all the boot problems of ubuntu. Since windows have safe mode and it fixes most of the problems.

Comment: All the Ubuntu users need much better automatic solution than Windows so that every user need not spend time on R&D on Ubuntu.

Comment: You've done things that have just complicated matters; I would never have run boot-repair; expecting `fsck` alone to have detected and fixed the issue caused by power-outage (corrected for memory that wasn't sync'd to disk), but boot-repair makes changes and if run before the `fsck` it's likely to have introduced many many more issues.  GRUB_CMDLINE* looks like it's from /etc/default/grub which you wouldn't touch; the change I made impacts the next boot only being a change in RAM during boot. There are recovery tools but having run boot-repair (when run matters) I can't advise sorry

Comment: level 1 worked fine for me. able to get back the normal screen but with wierd icons on right side and on desktop.
You're an experienced person but not everyone available on blogs and other sources. Corrected the GRUB_CMDLINE before setting to level1. Believe the themes are disturbed. Will remove and check.

Answer (score 0):

Open it in recovery mode. and it will boot up after clicking resume. i am also having same issue. i will update if any way is done. for temporary advance option recovery would work.